# How can I self-host the privileged or certified Firefox OS application on my web server?

Tags: manifest, firefox-os

We have developed a Firefox OS application. Now that I want to install the application in Firefox OS device from my local webserver,I have followed the steps given in this link:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Marketplace/Options/Self_publishing

Now that I am able to host the application and install in device from the link pointing to that web server. This scenario is working only if the application "manifest.webapp" is having

```
"type":"web"
```

or if we are not defining any "type".

It is failed to install when I change the "type" in manifest.webapp file to

```
"type":"certified"
```

or

```
"type":"privileged"
```

Is there any other change I do have to make so that certified and privileged applications also become installable?

Comment: https://marketplace.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/overview.html Here, you might get a market place up and running. This will let you serve certified apps but I believe certified apps needs to be signed and even if you sign them with your own keys, it might not work as it might have to be signed by a mozilla key.

Answer (score 1):

As of now certified apps are giving only to the OEM and Firefox OS development team can make. Normal developers can't make it.

Usually Privileged apps should be submitted to Official Firefox Marketplace, these app will have to undergo Code review before they are pushed to Marketplace, for downloading.

Check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Firefox_OS/Security/Security_model#Secure_App_Update_Process

Comment: Actually my issue is I want to host on my local web server not marketplace. In order to install application we have to connect phone to pc with usb or host the installable file on some server (not marketplace) so that any one who can access that server can download and install. I am looking for second option.

Comment: @user3878988 privileged apps can only be installed from the mozilla marketplace... yet, you could try to host your own market place. This is a limit because privileged apps and certified apps can have access to `dangerous` permissions.

Comment: ok, got it. So there is no other option to host privileged or certified apps in local server similar to web apps.